# Chopping up files using bash commands in python is running slow 'tail: stdout: Broken pipe'

Tags: python, bash, file

I just want to automate the extraction of small samples from two tsv files. The row where the samples are taken don't necessarily have to be precise, every sample just needs to be evenly spaced. When the cutting happens the bash shell outputs 'tail: stdout: Broken pipe' although the program still seems to run okay at first. I don't particularly like that my program outputs the word 'Broken' but I don't really care. The problem is each subsequent 'chopping' takes longer, and I can't figure out why. Do I have a memory leak? Is there something I should close? I also don't like having the try except statement but I'm not sure of a good way around it.

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import commands
import csv as tsv
def main(scorebreaks, positives, negatives):
    #just to isolate the attributeId
    newpositives = os.path.basename(positives)
    attributeid = newpositives.rstrip('-positive.tsv')
    #create output folder if it doesn't exist 
    path_to_script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(positives))
    newpath = path_to_script_dir + '/ezcut_output'
    if not os.path.exists(newpath): os.makedirs(newpath)


    with open(scorebreaks, 'rb') as tsvfile:
        tsvreader = tsv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter='\t')
        scorebreakslist = zip(*(line.strip().split('\t') for line in tsvfile))
        #print scorebreakslist[0][1] #would give line number at .99
        #print scorebreakslist[1][1] #would give .99
    whatiteration = input('What iteration? ')
    chunksize = input('Chunk size? ')
    numberofchunks = int(input('Number of chunks? '))-1
    scorejumpamt = 1.0/numberofchunks #number of chunks is 20? score jump amt == .05
    #print scorejumpamt
    scorei = 1.0
    choparray = [100]
    while True: #cause i needed a do-while loop
        scorei = float(scorei) - float(scorejumpamt)
        scorei = '%.2f'%(scorei)
        #print scorei
        if float(scorei) < 0.00: break
        try:
            arraynum = scorebreakslist[1].index(str(scorei))
        except ValueError:
            break
        #print scorebreakslist[1]
        #add the linenumber to an array for use in cutting
        choparray.append(scorebreakslist[0][arraynum])
    #print len(choparray)
    #the actual file manipulation section of code
    index=0
    for number in choparray:
        indexkinda = 1-float(scorejumpamt)*float(index)
        indexkinda = '%.2f'%(indexkinda)
        #print indexkinda
        if indexkinda < 0: break
        if float(indexkinda) > 0.50:
            #print indexkinda
            cmd = 'tail -n+%s %s | head -n%s > %s/%s-%s-%s.tsv' % (number, positives, chunksize, newpath, indexkinda, attributeid, whatiteration)
            subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
            #subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
            index+=1
        else: #maybe make this not get anything below 0.1 for speed
            #print indexkinda
            cmd = 'tail -n+%s %s | head -n%s > %s/%s-%s-%s.tsv' % (number, negatives, chunksize, newpath, indexkinda, attributeid, whatiteration)
            subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
            index+=1
main(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this all wrong. You shouldn't be spawning subprocesses at all, and especially you shouldn't tell them to repeatedly reread the same parts of the file.

Just use the python `file` class to iterate over lines. Please.

Comment: I'm not re-reading the same parts of any file though? the 'tail -n+(somenumber) takes the bottom part of the file. So the same parts of the file are never read.

Comment: @user2005645, no, `tail` has to reread all those lines in order to skip them. There is no way to directly say "skip to the nth line in a file".